# XPath JMeter Assertion : Error "prefix must resolve to a namespace"

Tags: xpath, jmeter, performance-testing, xml-namespaces

I am trying to use [JMeter XPath Assertion](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#XPath_Assertion) on a tag value as below with XPath assertion command:

```
//m:CurrencyNameResul/text() = Pounds
```

Webservice Response:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <soap:Body>
    <m:CurrencyNameResponse xmlns:m="http://www.oorsprong.org/websamples.countryinfo">
      <m:CurrencyNameResult>Pounds</m:CurrencyNameResult>
    </m:CurrencyNameResponse>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

I am getting error

> prefix must resolve to a namespace

and after referring to JMeter manual below:

```
NAMESPACES As a work-round for namespace limitations of the Xalan XPath parser implementation on which JMeter is based, you can provide a Properties file which contains mappings for the namespace prefixes:
prefix1=Full Namespace 1
prefix2=Full Namespace 2
…
You reference this file in jmeter.properties file using the property:
xpath.namespace.config
```

I don't get it, so my questions are:

- what should be the content of Properties file?
- where to put its path?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is how to proceed:

Create in jmeter/bin folder a file named namespaces.properties containing:

> m=http://www.oorsprong.org/websamples.countryinfo

In user.properties set:

> xpath.namespace.config=namespaces.properties

Finally fix your assertion to contain:

> //m:CurrencyNameResult = 'Pounds'

And check **"Use Namespaces"**

To end up with:

[image: XPath Assertion configuration]

Comment: Thanks @ubikloadpack  for your detailed answer, it works like a charm, really appreciated it :)

Answer (score 2):

You can amend your XPath query to use [name()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/XPath/Functions/name) function like:

```
(//*[name() = 'm:CurrencyNameResult'])/text()
```

and you will not have to mess up with amending properties, restarting JMeter, etc.

[image: JMeter Xpath Name]

Moreover if you go for [local-name()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/XPath/Functions/local-name) function instead you will not have to include the namespace prefix into your query:

```
(//*[local-name() = 'CurrencyNameResult'])/text()
```

More information:

- [XPath language specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xpath-19991116/)
- [Using the XPath Extractor in JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/using-xpath-extractor-jmeter-0)
- [XPath Tutorial](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xpath_intro.asp)