# Unable to extract xml value from response using path extractor

Tags: xpath, jmeter

I am trying to extract value of an element "Value" from XML response in Jmeter. But I am getting an error. Also, it's not even formatted response. so I am using tidy

Assertion error: false
Assertion failure: true
Assertion failure message: Index -1 out of bounds for length 128
See log file for further details.

I have specified settings as below:

Apply to: Main sample only
XML parsing options: Use tidy
Match No: -1
xpath query: //ExecuteSearchResponse/Object/Property/Value

Response::

```
--A-B--MIME-BOUNDARY--81cc957fd054e56a-16be7163b33--Y-Z
Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary
Content-Type: application/xop+xml; type="application/soap+xml"; charset=UTF-8
Content-ID: <abc.com>

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><e:Envelope xmlns:d="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:fn35d="http://abc/schema" xmlns:fn35="http://www.abcmmk/schema" xmlns:fn40d="http://abc/schema" xmlns:fn40m="http://www.abc/schema" xmlns:fn40="http://www.BC/schema" xmlns:dime="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2002/04/reference/" xmlns:xop="http://www.w3.org/2004/08/xop/include" xmlns:e="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"><e:Body><ExecuteSearchResponse xmlns="http://www.example.com/schema"><Object classId="QueryResultRow"><Property i:type="fn40:SingletonId" propertyId="Id"><Value>{F286669A-F313-4420-BCD1-878E6C5D0264}</Value></Property></Object><CollectionTerminator i:type="fn40:EndOfCollection"></CollectionTerminator></ExecuteSearchResponse></e:Body></e:Envelope>
```

--A-B--MIME-BOUNDARY--81cc957fd054e56a-16be7163b33--Y-Z--

I was expecting to have Value - {F286669A-F313-4420-BCD1-878E6C5D0264} extricated and saved in the variable but I am getting error instead. Not sure what am I doing wrong. Or if there is a better way to do so, please suggest.

Comment: Have you checked what the outcome of xpath?

Comment: Did you configure XML namespaces? [Here's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52264871/xpath-jmeter-assertion-error-prefix-must-resolve-to-a-namespace) something about that.

Comment: Use full path `/e:Envelope/e:Body/ExecuteSearchResponse/ CollectionTerminator/ Object/Property/Value`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot use [XPath Extractor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#XPath_Extractor) for plain text, it assumes **structured data** such as XML, [XHTML](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XHTML) or HTML.

If you provided the full response and there is only one `<Value>` tag there - the easiest is just going for [Boundary Extractor](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/the-boundary-extractor-vs-the-regular-expression-extractor-in-jmeter/) as getting the text between `<Value>` and `</Value>` would be as simple as specifying these left and right boundary:

[image]